# How to use a function of component1 in component2 in Angular 6 without interaction of HTML?

Tags: angular, angular6, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I have testTry() function in Component1 which accepts one parameter and prints the value.

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

 testTry(name:any){
 console.log("Name-->",name);}

 ngOnInit(){    }

}
```

I have component2 with a function sampleCall() in which i need to call a function of component1 by sending a parameter

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

 sampleCall(){
  let a = "Sravya";
  testTry(a);
}

 ngOnInit(){    }
}
```

How would I call a function from component1 to component2 without involving HTML?

Comment: move that function to service

Comment: is there any other option other than that?

Comment: you can use eventEmmiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`@ViewChild`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild),

We can use this to get control for `Child Component` inside `Parent Component`. When we used it, we will get the child Component as **`Object`** so that we are able to call the methods and variables of the the Child Component.

**Component2.ts**

```
 @ViewChild(Component1) component1: Component1;

 sampleCall() {
  let a = "Sravya";
  this.component1.testTry(a);
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: Its not a generic solution as it requires `Component1` to be inside `Component2`

Comment: OP's question is without interaction of html then, I think using `@ViewChild` is better than Injecting it into another component.

Comment: @ganesh045 : i think he had parent child relationship then. Cool. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

1. Create a service and move the method inside the service
2. Inject `component1` into `component2` (not recommended)

Try:

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

constructor(private comp1: Component1){}

sampleCall(){
  let a = "Sravya";
  this.comp1.testTry(a);
}

 ngOnInit(){    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above solutions, which are logically correct, you can also **use Inheritance** (a less used feature of typescript).

**Keep all the functions in a separate file** like `common-logic.ts` and other components can simply access them using `extends` keyword.

```js
export class Component2 extends CommonLogic {}
```

**Component2**

```js
export class Component2 implements OnInit extends CommonLogic {

 sampleCall(){
  let a = "Sravya";
  testTry(a);
 }
```

**CommonLogic**

```js
export class CommonLogic {

 testTry(name:any){
   console.log("Name-->",name);
 }

}
```

Note: Angular only allows inheritance up to one level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventEmmiter as below.

ChangeService.ts

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
export class ChangeService {
  calltestTry: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}
  emitcalltestTryEvent(data) {
    this.calltestTry.emit(data);
  }
  getcalltestTryEmitter() {
    return this.calltestTry;
  }
}
```

component1.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
})
export class ComponentOne {
  item: number = 0;
  subscription: any;
  constructor(private changeService:ChangeService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.changeService.getcalltestTryEmitter()
      .subscribe(item => this.testTry(item));
  }
  testTry(item: string) {
     console.log(item);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

component2.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
})
export class ComponentTwo {
  item: number = 0;
  subscription: any;
  constructor(private changeService:ChangeService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sampleCall(item: number) {
     let a = "Sravya";
     this.changeService.emitcalltestTryEvent(a);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 4 ways of doing this.

1. Including the function in a service, so that you can inject it anywhere.
2. Making your function static, so that you can access it using the Class. (Pros and Cons are there)
3. Inject the component to the other component so that you can access it (Not recommended).
4. Pass your function as an input parameter to the other component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ComponentFactoryResolver to get components and use their properties.

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

 testTry(name:any){
   console.log("Name-->",name);
 }

 ngOnInit(){    }

}

import {ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('parent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private _cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  sampleCall(){
    const comp = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(Component1);
    const component1Ref = this.container.createComponent(comp);
    const component1 = component1Ref.instance;
    component1._ref = component1Ref;

    let a = "Sravya";
    component1.testTry(a);
 }

  ngOnInit(){    }
}
```